# Google Sheets Script code takes long time - for-loop

Tags: javascript, database, for-loop, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I wrote a code and it works quite well. The only problem is that it takes a little too long to complete. The loop should be able to process up to a maximum of 20 data sets (10 from LOOP1 and another 10 from LOOP2) at once.
If I start the function with 2 data sets, for example, I currently have a waiting time of 10-20s.

Maybe you have tips on how I can make the script faster.
I've already tried a few things:

- while
- foreach
- const and let instead of var

But nothing made the script run faster.

````js
function data (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("database is being updated", "...loading", 15); 

  var targetSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd.MM.yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var rangeE = as.getRange('M9').getValue();
  var rangeB = as.getRange('M22').getValue();
  var collect = as.getRange('G2').getValue();
  
  var rangefind = targetSheet2.getRange('F2:F');

  // LOOP1
  if (rangeE != 0) {
    var row1 = 9 + rangeE;
    var statusE = "B";
    for(var i = 0; i < rangeE; i++){
      if(as.getRange(row1-i, 12, 1, 1).getValue() ==  true){
            var order1 = as.getRange(row1-i, 6, 1, 1).getValue();
            var batch1 = as.getRange(row1-i, 7, 1, 1).getValue();
            var nc1 = as.getRange(row1-i, 8, 1, 1).getValue();
            var rm1 = as.getRange(row1-i, 9, 1, 1).getValue();
            var vz1 = as.getRange(row1-i, 10, 1, 1).getValue();
            var lastRow2 = targetSheet1.getLastRow();
            targetSheet1.getRange(lastRow2 + 1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusE, order1, batch1, nc1, rm1, vz1]]);

        ``` How I can make it with textFinder - thats my problem ```
            
            var textFinder = rangefind.createTextFinder(order1).matchEntireCell(true);
            var result = textFinder.findAll(); 
            var row2 = result[result.length - 1].getRow();
            targetSheet2.getRange(row2, 2, 1, 4).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusE]]);     
        }
    }
    var rangecheckE = as.getRange(10, 12, 10, 1);
    rangecheckE.uncheck();
  }

  // LOOP2
  if (rangeB != 0) {
    var row1 = 22 + rangeB;
    var statusB = "A";
    for(var i = 0; i < rangeB; i++){
      if(as.getRange(row1-i, 12, 1, 1).getValue() ==  true){
            var order2 = as.getRange(row1-i, 6, 1, 1).getValue();
            var batch2 = as.getRange(row1-i, 7, 1, 1).getValue();
            var nc2 = as.getRange(row1-i, 8, 1, 1).getValue();
            var rm2 = as.getRange(row1-i, 9, 1, 1).getValue();
            var vz2 = as.getRange(row1-i, 10, 1, 1).getValue();
            var lastRow3 = targetSheet1.getLastRow();
            targetSheet1.getRange(lastRow3 + 1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusB, order2, batch2, nc2, rm2, vz2]]);

        ``` How I can make it with textFinder - thats my problem ```
            
            var textFinder = rangefind.createTextFinder(order2).matchEntireCell(true);
            var result = textFinder.findAll(); 
            var row2 = result[result.length - 1].getRow();
            targetSheet2.getRange(row2, 2, 1, 4).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusB]]);
        }
    }
    var rangecheckB = as.getRange(23, 12, 10, 1);
    rangecheckB.uncheck();
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Data has been updated successfully", "OK", 6);
}
````

**UPDATE 1:
Here is the new version from my script and it's really a litle bit faster.**

```js
function data (){  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("database is being updated", "...loading", 15); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var targetSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var rangecheck1 = as.getRange(10, 12, 10, 1);
  var rangecheck2 = as.getRange(23, 12, 10, 1);
  var rangefind = targetSheet2.getRange('F2:F');
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var collect = as.getRange('G2').getValue();
  var dataE = as.getRange('F10:L19').getValues();
  var dataB = as.getRange('F23:L32').getValues();
  var outdataE = [];
  var outdataB = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (dataE[i][6] === true && dataE[i][0] > 0) {
    outdataE.push([dataE[i][0],dataE[i][1],dataE[i][2],dataE[i][3],dataE[i][4]]);    
    } 
    if (dataB[i][6] === true && dataB[i][0] > 0) {
    outdataB.push([dataB[i][0],dataB[i][1],dataB[i][2],dataB[i][3],dataB[i][4]]); 
    } 
    }

  if (outdataE.length > 0) {
    var statusE = "B";
    for (var i = 0; i < outdataE.length; i++) {
    var lastRow = targetSheet1.getLastRow();
    var rowi = rangefind.createTextFinder(outdataE[i][0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow();
    targetSheet1.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusE, outdataE[i][0], outdataE[i][1], outdataE[i][2], outdataE[i][3], outdataE[i][4]]]);
    targetSheet2.getRange(rowi, 2, 1, 4).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusE]]);
    }
  }

  if (outdataB.length > 0) {  
    var statusB = "A";
    for (var i = 0; i < outdataB.length; i++) {
    var lastRow = targetSheet1.getLastRow();
    var rowi = rangefind.createTextFinder(outdataB[i][0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow();
    targetSheet1.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusB, outdataB[i][0], outdataB[i][1], outdataB[i][2], outdataB[i][3], outdataB[i][4]]]);
    targetSheet2.getRange(rowi, 2, 1, 4).setValues([[date, email, collect, statusB]]); 
    }
  }

  rangecheck1.uncheck();
  rangecheck2.uncheck();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Data has been updated successfully", "OK", 6);
}
```

Do you think I can make it much more faster with another modification? Or is thats the limit...?

**UPDATE2: Here are screenshots from my database for a better understanding.**

[targetsheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unQfc.png)

[targetsheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i8Fy.png)

1. the data comes IN with a formula (maximum 10 rows at once time)
2. the script copies every row from the IN-data at lastRow in targetsheet1
3. the script searches with textfinder the order from every row of the IN-data in targetsheet2. If there's a match the targetsheet2-data in this line is overwritten with the new IN-data

I hope you can understand a bit better, what my script should do...

**UPDATE3: Here is a sample-data**

[SampleData](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TIHEbuZe1d3BIq4xl7fpfJZbyCnEo5iCepv0zdABM9c/edit#gid=1803017680)

I just can't get any further and need help. the data is larger in the original file. Therefore, the script only requires a fraction of the processing time.

I use the text finder to look for the same number in sheet2 of my table as in main. This data record is then adjusted accordingly in sheet2.

I hope I have described it in a somewhat understandable way.

Comment: _EDIT: Sorry, but the link is not helping me_ I don’t understand what this means. Would you please explain. Would you also edit the question to include sample data.

Comment: The delay in the loops is because you are executing _getRange_ and _get Values_ **INSIDE** the loop. It would be better to get the data **BEFORE** the loop, and then use a loop variable to select the relevant data INSIDE the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modificated the script and its just a bit faster. Do you think I can make it much more faster? Or is thats the limit?

Comment: Bear in mind that the question does not include any data however... In the second half of the script, loops `for (var i = 0; i < outdataE.length; i++) {`... and `for (var i = 0; i < outdataB.length; i++) {` include `setvalues()` commands - these are time intensive. An option would be to save these values  to a temporary array, and use a single `setValues(temporaryArray)` at the conclusion of each loop. Also, we have no information about what `createTextFinder` is doing and whether this is the most appropriate method for this purpose.

Comment: Hey Tedinoz. I updated my post. I think know it's better to understand what my script should do. Can you explain me how I do the temporaryArray? Maybe you can adjust my script - that would be fantastic.

Comment: “Maybe you can adjust my script” Sure, but please do NOT provide sample data only by way of an image. This just makes it harder and longer (and so, it is a disincentive) for a user to Consider your question. Any sample data should be included in the body of the  question.

Comment: This is quite ridiculous without raw data; the script identifies three sheets: the active sheet, Sheet1 and Sheet2. Please supply sample data for all sheets and an example of the expected outcome. Also please explain your understanding of the purpose of `createTextFinder`.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz. I updated my question. Also I added a link to a sample-data... I hope for help :-)

Comment: @frealk While links and images might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. This means that you should add sample data as text. Adding an image of sample data should be done only when there is something that can't be shown as plain text.

Comment: @Wicket: Tedinoz said that I should add a file and not images. I did this in my UPDATE 3. Now you think I should integrate the whole thing as text in the post!? Where is the difference. It's easier to access a file.